# Python Thread Hangs

Tags: python, multithreading, freeze

Seems anytime I try to start a background thread, you never reach code beneath it until the thread finishes.  This is Python 3.6.5

I had this problem with a more complicated app, but it doesn't appear to be related to multiprocessing or subprocesses.

The following code never prints 'FG works':

```
import sys
import time
import threading

def bgthread():
    while True:
        print('BG works')
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(1)  

threading.Thread(bgthread()).start()

while True:
    print('FG works')
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(1)
```

If anyone sees my obvious mistake, please chime in.

Answer (score 4):

You do not want to call the function when starting the new thread, as this will block the main thread. You should do,

```
threading.Thread(target=bgthread).start()
```

This is because the call to the `Thread` initializer is invoking `bgthread` instead of referring to it in order to start later.